# Goerli Testnet: TypeError: "chainid" is not supported by the VM version

Tags: solidity, testnets, solidity-0.8.x, goerli

I am trying to get the network's chainid using the new Solidity feature in 0.8.0 `block.chainId`. In particular, I am trying to create an EIP712_DOMAIN using the following code in my smart contract

```
        EIP712_DOMAIN = keccak256(abi.encode(
            keccak256("EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract)"),
            keccak256(bytes("Purchase")),
            keccak256(bytes("v1")),
            block.chainid,
            address(this)
        ));
```

My contract version is `pragma solidity ^0.8.9;` however when I run this code on Goerli, I get the following error:

`CompileError: TypeError: "chainid" is not supported by the VM version.`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my truffle config:

```
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.12",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true,
          runs: 9999
        },
        evmVersion: "byzantium" //<------ error
      }
    }
  },
```

I needed to update my evm version to `istanbul`